# Create a range that shifts after each iteration of a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range, iteration

I am new to python and coding in general and I am trying to create a "for" loop with a range, similar to this one:

```
for n in range(0,number_of_files)
   for i in range(0,5)
```

but this times, make it so that the loop that controls i adds 5 for every iteration of n, creating a result like this:

```
i=[0,1,2,3,4,5](next iteration of n)[6,7,8,9,10],etc...
```

I could chain ranges but i don't know how many files there are in the folder and it would add a lot of code.

**Update :**

I succeeded in getting what I wanted even if it may not be the most elegant solution, I used the structure from one of the answers :

```
i = 0
for n in range(0,number_of_files):
    for ii in range(i,i+5):
        {code}
    i += 5
```

What I was trying to do was:

**Go over all the excel files in a folder, take the name of the person and 
create a new excel file with all the names stacked up.**

The need for the 2 loops is that the first one would go over all the files and do its thing. The second one needed to stack the names but according to the number of rows in the first file (each person doesn't have the same number of rows). In summary, the result would look like this.

```
**name   /   surname   /   age   / date / time / statistics**
patient A/ surname A /   age A  / date / hours / statistics 1
patient A/ surname A /   age A  / date / hours / statistics 2
patient A/ surname A /   age  A / date / hours / statistics 3
patient A/ surname A /   age  A / date / hours / statistics 4
patient B/ surname B /   age  B / date / hours / statistics 1
patient C/ surname C /   age  C / date / hours / statistics 1
patient C/ surname C /   age  C / date / hours / statistics 1
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Your output is not consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.count`:

```
from itertools import count

def chunked_range(num_of_chunks, size_of_chunk):
    for i in range(num_of_chunks):
        yield [*iter(lambda c=count(): i * size_of_chunk + next(c), size_of_chunk * (i + 1))]

for i in chunked_range(3, 5):
    print('i =', i)
```

Prints:

```
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
i = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
i = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is increment your range by 5 on each pass of the inner loop.

```
i = 0
for n in range(0,number_of_files):
    for ii in range(i,i+5):
        {code}
    i += 5
```

This will loop through the files and increment by 5.

Comment: Tkank you for such a quick and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the expected result:

```
x = 0
for n in range(0,number_of_files):
    for i in range(x,x+5):
        ###
    x+=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can step the outer loop by a constant factor:

```
number_of_files = 3
step = 5
for n in range (0, number_of_files * step, step):
   for i in range(0, step):
       j = i + n
       print(j)
       # code goes here
```

example: https://ideone.com/iWZUTR

output (as expected):

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: If this were the expected output, then why wouldn't you just use a simple `range(number_of_files * step)`?

Comment: @Sayse because there is still the requirement to loop across files.  If not for that, a simple range would be the obvious answer.  I made the assumption that there was some reason for the split loops, even though it was not fully expressed in the question.  e.g. https://ideone.com/W9yCIm which prints out a line for each file

Comment: The output is incorrect. First loop should give `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and not `[0,1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @SebastienD that's an inconsistency with the code in his question.  He appears to want 5 outputs per "file"  If he wants 6 per file, then changing the step is easy enough.

Comment: yeah you're correct, code and output do not match

Answer (score 0):

Okay yes without knowing what you are expecting to get with your output and or its implementation it is very difficult to ascertain the solution you need.  For instance reading your question literally I would suggest the following:

```
for n in range(0,number_of_files)
    i = n  (or just n)
```

This would get you the results (sort-of) that you have listed (see below) regardless of how many files exit if you needed to do something every 5 or 6 files (0-5 = 6 iterations but 6-10 = 5 iterations) then (n mod 6 or 5) == 0 would work

```
n=[0,1,2,3,4,5](continued iteration)[6,7,8,9,10],etc...
```

As stated your question is inconsistent and incomplete and the above denotes why this is the case and why it makes it hard to answer it -- perhaps if you adjusted your question you would get the results you are looking for assuming that the various assumptions on what you wanted did not answer it already

Answer (score -1):

You want to keep an accumulator with the number of iterations of `i`

```
counter = 0
for n in range(0,number_of_files)
   for i in range(0,5)
       #Code goes here
    counter += 5
```